# Sort 2nd Field Descending from text file perl

Tags: perl, sorting, file-io, text-files, numeric

I have a text file, tab delimited that looks like this in the format, name and age:

```
chris     19
bobby     29
doofus    67
```

I wanted to pull in the text file, and then sort via the second field. I can pull in the text file, and format the data, but I can't sort it right and as such have removed the sort code I had...

Here is the simple file pull: How could I modify it?

```
open (FILEHERE, 'ages.txt');
while (<FILEHERE>) {
chomp;
my($n, $s) = split("\t");
print "$a\t $s";
}
close (FILEHERE);
```

Comment: Do you need to use Perl?  How bout using `sort -nk2 file`?  This will sort numerically on the second column.

Comment: Going to be using perl it's just one part of a bigger product!

Comment: See also: [Sorting an array or table by column in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112465/how-to-sort-an-array-or-table-by-column-in-perl/27135781#27135781)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the file into an array of array references and then sort based on each array's second field:

```
my @lines;
open (FILEHERE, 'ages.txt');
while(<FILEHERE>) {
    push @lines, [split /\t/];
}

my @sorted = sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] } @lines;
```

Or, what might be easier is to write your Perl script assuming that your data is sorted properly, and just read from stdin: `sort -grk2 ages.txt | perl yourscript.pl`

Comment: result : 

ARRAY(0x47973e0) ARRAY(0x4691990) ARRAY(0x47973b0)
 

Memory references?

Comment: Yep, each line is stored as an array, and the content of `@sorted` is references to those arrays.  To get the array referred to by `$a`, use `@{$a}`.

Comment: Trying to print @sorted .. And it gave me the above, so I try to print @{$a} and I get :
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at ... line 406, <FILEHERE> line 3.

Comment: You need to iterate over the values of the array: try `print $_->[0], "\t", $_->[1] foreach @sorted`.  Or more explicitly: `foreach my $l (@sorted) { print $l->[0], "\t", $l->[1] }`

Comment: god send, such simplicity been at this for 8 hours straight. CHeers

Answer (score 4):

A [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) (ST) can help here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = <<END;
chris     19
doofus    67
bobby     29
END

open my $fh, '<', \$data or die $!;

print map $_->[0],
sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
map { [ $_, /(\d+)$/ ] }
<$fh>;

close $fh;
```

Output:

```
chris     19
bobby     29
doofus    67
```

Read from the bottom of the ST up.  The routine takes a file line, and then within `map` places that line as the first element of an anonymous array.  The second element is the captured numeric value, from the second column.  The `sort` takes an anonymous subroutine to sort on the anonymous array's second element (thus, the dereferencing arrow operator `$a->[1]`).  The results are passed to `map` to access the sorted lines and those are finally printed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: While using in-memory files is a wonderful thing, you just might want to use the `DATA` filehandle for this.

Comment: I tried adapating this to pull in a file using open (FILE, 'ages.txt) or w.e and it didn't work. It is an external file. 

Possible you can explain how to get it to work like that? Or am I being stupid?

Comment: @amon - This is a good suggestion.  Originally started with `__DATA__` but went this route thinking the OP could just substitute a file name for the value of `$data`.

Comment: @Mombassa - You can do this: `my $data = 'ages.txt';` and then remove the leading backslash before `$data` in the `open`: `open my $fh, '<', $data or die $!;`

Answer (score 1):

This one liner from [How to sort an array or table by column in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112465/how-to-sort-an-array-or-table-by-column-in-perl/27135781#27135781) should work:

```
perl -anE 'push @t,[@F]}{ say "@$_" for sort {$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]} @t' names.txt
```

As with @reo katoa it uses an array of arrays - but leverages `-a` to autosplit the lines into `@F` first. See [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for details on autosplit.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call `sort -k 2,2` in perl to sort the file on 2nd field, of course use `-n` if they are numbers and `-r` to do a reverse sort.

I use the following one-liner to see squid access logs, it shows the longest sessions at top

```
sort -rn -k 2,2 access.log | perl -lpe 's/^([0-9]{10})(.\d{3})/scalar localtime$1/e'
```