# How can I sort an array or table by column in Perl?

Tags: sorting, perl

I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this, and I just can't get it to work.

I have an input file that is read into an array using Perl. The file is a text file containing a table. Perl reads it in as an array, with each element being a full line (including all five columns). This is what the array looks like:

```
0__len__340      16    324       0    0.0470588235294118
1__len__251      2     249       0    0.00796812749003984
2__len__497      0     497       0    0
3__len__55       7     48        0    0.127272727272727
4__len__171      0     171       0    0
5__len__75       0     75        0    0
6__len__160      75    85        0    0.46875
7__len__285      1     284       0    0.00350877192982456
8__len__94       44    50        0    0.468085106382979
```

I need to sort this table by the last column in descending order. So my output should be:

```
6__len__160     75    85       0    0.46875
8__len__94      44    50       0    0.468085106382979
3__len__55      7     48       0    0.127272727272727
0__len__340     16    324      0    0.0470588235294118
1__len__251     2     249      0    0.00796812749003984
7__len__285     1     284      0    0.00350877192982456
2__len__497     0     497      0    0
4__len__171     0     171      0    0
5__len__75      0     75       0    0
```

I've tried a few approaches, but none have worked. Here's the code I've tried:

```
@input = <FILENAME>;

#Close the file
close FILENAME;

my @fractions;
my $y = 0;
for (my $x = 1; $x <= $#input; ++$x) {
    $fractions[$y] = (split (/\s/, $input[$x]))[4];
    ++$y;
}
my @sorted = sort {$b <=> $a} @fractions;
my $e = 1;
my $z = 0;
my $f = 0;
my @final;

do {
    do {
        if ((split (/\s/, $input[$e]))[4] == $sorted[$z]){
            $final[$f] = $input[$e];
            ++$e;
            ++$f;
        } else {
            ++$e;
        }
    } until ($e > $#input);

    do {
        ++$z;
    } until ($sorted[$z] != $sorted[$z - 1]);

    $e = 0;
} until ($z > $#sorted);

for (my $h = 0; $h <= $#final; ++$h) {
    print $final[$h] . "\n\n";
}
```

With this one, I basically tried to put the column 5 numbers into their own array, sort them, and then go back through the original array and pull out the elements that match the sorted array, and put them into the final array.

This may work if I keep working on it, but it takes so long to run that it's impractical. This small table I'm using to test my code with took a long time for this to run, and once the code is working it will be dealing with a table that has millions of rows.

I also tried applying the sort command to the table itself, but my output is the exact same table as my input...it doesn't get sorted.

```
@input = <FILENAME>;
close FILENAME;
my @sorted = sort { $b->[4] <=> $a->[4] } @input;
for (my $h = 0; $h <= $#sorted; ++$h) {
    print $sorted[$h] . "\n\n";
}
exit;
```

Lastly, I tried to put the array into a hash where the key was the first four columns, since the first column name is unique, and the values being the fifth column.

Then I hoped I could sort the hash by the values and the keys would stay with their assigned values. I couldn't get this to work either, though unfortunately it was a couple days ago and I erased the code.

One problem was that I couldn't figure out how to split the string only before the fifth column, so I end up with two strings, one containing the first four columns and one containing the fifth.

What am I doing wrong with the sort command? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "portable" emergency when not on Unix sort :-)  `perl -E 'say sort { (split(/\s+/,$b))[4] <=> (split(/\s+/,$a))[4] } <>'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your last code example you can replace

```
my @sorted = sort { $b->[4] <=> $a->[4] } @input;
```

with

```
my @sorted = sort { (split(' ', $b))[4] <=> (split(' ', $a))[4] } @input;
```

or even

```
my @sorted = sort { (split(/\s+/, $b))[4] <=> (split(/\s+/, $a))[4] } @input;
```

if input data has no lines with leading spaces.

Comment: note that the essential thing here is splitting on `' '` (which is special shorthand for splitting on `/\s+/` but ignoring leading whitespace too) rather than on `/\s/` (which splits on a single whitespace, leading to the "fifth column" not actually containing the desired data, since most columns are separated by multiple spaces)

Comment: @ysth yes, I'm aware of that, but can't see line in example above which would be problematic in that sense?

Comment: That works, thank you so much! I had tried inserting the split function into my sort statement before, but maybe using /\s/ instead of ' ' was messing it up, or I made some other mistake. Thanks again!

Comment: @Lisa as some has already mentioned, `\s` splits data only on ONE white space character, while in your case there are many of them between columns, so `\s+` which takes them all into account is more appropriate.

Comment: @mpapec @ysth  see oneliner variant above :-)  ... it always seems that a shorter version `map` and/or autosplit (with `@F`) should be possible but ...

Comment: See also `List::UtilsBy::nsort_by`

Answer (score 3):

In case this helps folks dropping by in the future - here are some inelegant attempts to `sort()` the content of `lines.txt` (data from question), by its fifth column, with a Perl one-liner. This should work:

```
perl -E 'say "@$_" for sort {$a->[4] <=> $b->[4]} map {[(split)]} <>' file
```

This is more or less the same thing but with the `split` "automated" with the autosplit (`-a`) switch which creates the `@F` array:

```
perl -anE 'push @t,[@F]}{say "@$_" for sort {$a->[4] <=> $b->[4]} @t' file
```

If the split pattern is not white space, you can substitute it for the default (`\s+`) shown here:

```
perl -E 'say sort {(split(/\s+/,$a))[4] <=> (split(/\s+/,$b))[4]} <>' file
```

This is the shortest way to `sort` and print the fifth column:

```
perl -E 'say for sort map{ (split)[4] } <>' file
```

**Transforming the sort**

Can we `map`, `split` and `sort` in one pass? This is a short way to sort the fifth column:

```
perl -E 'say for sort map{ [(split)[4], $_]->[0] } <>' file
```

Dissecting this last example: `perl` first `maps` the `STDIN` to `split()` - making a list; takes the fifth element (*i.e.* `[4]`) of this `split()` list and wraps that list item and the whole line that was just read (`$_`) inside an array constructor `[]`; then takes the first element of that anonymous array (i.e. the fifth column of each line) and passes it to `sort()`. Phew!

This just prints the fifth column since we only passed the first element `->[0]` of the anonymous array to `sort`. To print the whole line sorted by the column in this way we need  to pass the whole anonymous array to `sort` and tell `sort` to use the element which holds the column's contents to do its work, and then pass the other element of the anonymous array (the one that holds the entire line) to `print` (or `say`) - this way we can sort by the fifth column, but print out the whole line:

```
perl -E 'say $_->[1] for sort{$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]} map{[(split)[4], $_]} <>' file
```

This is just like our very first example above. If, instead of running through the list that is created using `for`, we `map` the second element and pass it to `print` we get:

```
perl -E 'say map $_->[1], sort{$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]} map{[(split)[4],$_]} <>' file
```

We have reinvented the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) which is such a great Perl idiom that it is ["built in" to Perl 6](http://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/day-23-unary-sort/) **;-)**

---

- To get a sense of how this works you can "visualize" things with [`Data::Printer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer):

  `perl -MDDP -e '@t = sort map{ [ (split /\s+/)[4], $_ ] } <> ; p @t' file`
- Learn more about Perl idioms from the [Perl Idioms Explained](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Perl%20Idioms%20Explained%20) posts at [perlmonks.org](http://www.perlmonks.org) and the [Perl Beyond Syntax](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2014/10-perl-beyond-syntax.html) chapter of [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You might also like the `nsort_by` function from `List::UtilsBy`:

```
use List::UtilsBy 'rev_nsort_by';

my @sorted = rev_nsort_by { (split(' ', $_))[4] } @input;
```