# How can I extract specific columns in perl?

Tags: perl

```
chr1    1   10  el1
chr1    13  20  el2
chr1    50  55  el3
```

I have this tab delimited file and I want to extract the second and third column using perl. How can I do that?

I tried reading the file using file handler and storing it in a string, then converting the string to an array but it didn't get me anywhere.

My attempt is:

```
while (defined($line=<FILE_HANDLE>)) {
    my @tf1;
    @tf1 = split(/\t/ , $line);
}
```

Comment: Is that the code as you've written it in your script? It's missing braces around the `while` code block which would generate an error if you'd put "use strict;" at the top of your script

Comment: my whole code is over 100 lines, it contains use strict and use warnings. This is just an excerpt

Comment: the code as is (with the added braces) should do what you want - so the problem is most likely elsewhere. an [mcve] would show us where the problem actually is

Comment: Is your code really as badly-formatted as that? I don't understand why people don't put more effort into formatting their code.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting of your code. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future. When you're asking strangers to read and understand your code, it's only polite to make it as easy to understand as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Simply autosplit on tab

```
#                                      ↓ index starts on 0
$ perl -F'\t' -lane'print join ",", @F[1,2]' inputfile
```

Output:

```
1,10
13,20
50,55
```

See [perlrun](http://p3rl.org/perlrun).

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;

my $input=shift or die "must provide <input_file> as an argument\n";

open(my $in,"<",$input) or die "Cannot open $input for reading: $!";

while(<$in>)
{
    my @tf1=split(/\t/,$_);
    print "$tf1[1]|$tf1[2]\n"; # $tf1[1] is the second column and $tf1[2] is the third column
}
close($in)
```

Answer (score 1):

What problem are you having? Your code already does all the hard parts.

```
while (defined($line=<FILE_HANDLE>)) {
    my @tf1;
    @tf1 = split(/\t/ , $line);
}
```

You have all three columns in your `@tf1` array (by the way - your variable naming needs serious work!) All you need to do now is to print the second and third elements from the array (but remember that Perl array elements are numbered from zero).

```
print "$tf1[1] / $tf1[2]\n";
```

It's possible to simplify your code quite a lot by taking advantage of Perl's default behaviours.

```
while (<FILE_HANDLE>) {          # Store record in $_
    my @tf1 = split(/\t/);       # Declare and initialise on one line
                                 # split() works on $_ by default
    print "$tf1[1] / $tf1[2]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even more pithily than @daxim as a one-liner:

```
perl -aE 'say "@F[1,2]" ' file
```

See also: [How to sort an array or table by column in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27112465/2019415)